# How many bits are sufficient to hash a webpage in english?

Tags: algorithm, hash

Recently I came by a question which asked , how many bits are sufficient to hash a webpage with these assumptions:

1. There are 1 billion web pages
2. The average length of web pages is 300 words
3. We have 250,000 words in English
4. The pages are in ASCII

Apparently there is no one right answer to this problem , but the aim of the question is to see how the general method works.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined what it means to “hash a webpage”; that phrase appears in this question and in a couple of other pages on Internet.  In those other pages it is used to mean computing a checksum (for example with `sha1sum`) to verify that content is intact.  If that's what you mean, then you need all the bits of any page that's to be “hashed”; on average, that is 300 * 8 * average English word length.  The question doesn't specify the average English word length, but if it is five letters plus a space, the average number of bits per page is 6*300*8 or 14400.

If you instead mean putting all the words of all the webpages into an index structure to allow a search to find all the webpages that contain any given set of words, one answer is about 10^13 bits:  There are 300 billion word references in a billion pages; each reference uses log_2(1G) bits, or about 30 bits, if references are stored naively; hence 9 trillion bits, or about 10^13.  You can also work out that naive storage for a billion URLs is at least an order of magnitude smaller than that, ie 10^12 bits at most.   Special methods might be used to reduce reference storage a couple orders of magnitude, but because URLs are easier to compress or save compactly (via, eg, a trie), reference storage is likely to still be far more than what is needed for storing URLs.

Comment: Is it possible to use this checksum in web crawling so to detect duplicate web pages ? (Not necessarily exact duplication , but having our checksum to generate quite unique checksums )

Comment: An ideal cryptographic hash function is sensitive to single-bit changes.  A function like `sha1sum` can be used to compute signatures to allow detection of duplicate pages, but cannot be used to detect *similar* webpages.  Let `P=sha1sum(original page)`, and for any modification at all, `Q=sha1sum(modified page)`.  On average I'd expect P to differ from Q in about half of its 160 bit positions.